# view over cte or temp table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have a table in staging layer(not indexed) which has close to 100 million rows. In the data warehouse layer, I need to select a certain number of rows from this table and join with another table, roughly having around 50 million rows, for which I use a cte now. From this cte, again some aggregations are carried out before joining with some other tables. So here, what will happen if use a view instead of the cte. I cannot test run it since it takes a lot of time.

So in a general aspect, which holds a slight advantage in terms of performance?

`cte` or `temp table` or `view` ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: A non materialized view should perform similarly to the CTE (I think).  If you go with a temp table, you pay a storage penalty, but then you can do things like add indices, which might speed up the join/query.  It depends on what your goals are.

Comment: Obviously, IO is the most expensive operation in majority systems so a temp table gets more badly performance coz it stored physically in the tempdb. You can find it in a list of table in the tempdb. If cte and view are identically then it has the same perfomance coz a view is just a stored query as cte.

Comment: I think you should go with local (single #) temporary table with indexes. Because first you will fetch the data from main table. Then you will apply some aggregations, looping and custom logic.

Comment: Probably neither. What are those tables? What are you trying to do? It *matters* **a lot**. For example, if you want to find changes by using an OUTR JOIN the best solution is to *not use any of them*. Use change tracking in the source tables to detect which rows in the source have changed

Comment: Then, *DON'T* apply the aggregations directly on the queries. Why use aggregations *at all*? You have OLAP cubes and SSAS Tabular for that. Just 1000x faster than manual aggregations. If you can't use them (**why**? is there a **real** reason?), you can use columstore tables. They are available in all editions, even Express and LocalDB since SQL Server 2016 SP1. They are available only on Enterprise in 2012 and later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with local (single #) temporary table with indexes. Because first you will fetch the data from main table. Then you will apply some aggregations, looping and custom logic. There will be few benefits :-

1. First whenever connection will close then local temporary table will dropped.
2. As you are saying you will get millions of records, then using index it will search faster.
3. Using temporary table and applying some aggregations will not put load on your main tables.

Comment: I'll add that the OP should create the table with `SELECT INTO` + `CREATE INDEX` rather than `CREATE TABLE`, as select into has reduced logging and will be much, much faster.

Comment: I'd say neither and the OP needs to explain the actual problem. Temporary tables are *not* used in data warehouse pipelines because of the fragmentation they'd cause and the need to recreate fine-tuned indexes. Big joins are typically NOT used for transformations, that's the job of SSIS. Big joins are avoided by using the built-in change tracking or even auditing columns

Comment: Aggregations are *not* pre-calculated either, that's the job of SSAS, OLAP or Tabular. If they can't be used, it's columnstore tables

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe the CTE is "created" once (when defined) and used once (when aggregated).

In general, this means that you should keep the code as a single query, letting the optimizer find the best execution path.

In general, materializing CTEs is going to be a bigger win when the CTE is referenced multiple times.  Often, you can get around multiple references using window functions, but that is a different matter.

That is general advice, but not always true.  Materializing a CTE as a temporary table can give two benefits:

- The query optimizer has a more accurate estimate of the number of rows for optimization.
- You can add indexes to boost performance.

The first is possibly not an issue, because you still have a large percentage of the original rows.  The second could  possibly help, but it is not a no-brainer.

You might want to create an indexed materialized view instead of a temporary table.  This would stay up-to-date and possibly be a big boost to performance.